# Libgdx + Eclipse + Admob

Tags: eclipse, gradle, libgdx, admob

I am trying to integrate Admob in my Libgdx project. I am using eclipse and I don't want to migrate to android studio. I don't find any proper guide on this.

My sdk is up to date: 27.0.3
Have installed Google play services and Google repository from Extras.

Now how can I integrate Admob in my project.

Answer (score 0):

To get more information about Admob in LibGDX, read:
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Admob-in-libgdx.
It's a documentation about how to implement and use Admob in your project.